# Passing 2 variables to 2 different html pages on django

Tags: django

I have 2 variables a,b(say) and 2 html pages x.html and y.html. I have a function called getdetails(), Where I get the details of a,b from the db and I want to send the 'a' value to x.html and b value to y.html while redirecting to x.html in the return.render() of getdetails() .How can I do that?

Comment: Please share some more details about your code. As in what exactly did you try, share some code snippets that you have tried. 

Make your questions as descriptive and easy to understand for others.

Comment: @rayy is right show your efforts

Comment: What do you even mean here? Why do you want to send data to an HTML page but not show it? Why can't you do everything in one view?

Comment: Possibly through Ajax.

Comment: why send a and b to those pages if you don't want to render them? do you want to save them so when you render x.html they are not lost?